# Batch get filename from path

Tags: batch-file, cygwin

Hi I don't have much experience in batch-programming and have a problem. I have a `.bat` script that reads a file with a list of paths and i want to get the filename of these paths. I use the script in **cygwin**.
My code in the Script:

```
for /F %%a in (error1.txt) do (
   set value=%%a
   FOR /F %%I IN ("%value%") DO SET MYPATHFILE=%%~nxI
)
```

When i run the Script `%value%` is empty.
Value of error1.txt:

```
a/b/c/d/TextIWant
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need delayed expansion or you can directly use %%a:

```
for /F %%a in (error1.txt) do (
   FOR /F %%I IN ("%%a") DO SET MYPATHFILE=%%~nxI
)
```

or

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%a in (error1.txt) do (
   set value=%%a
   FOR /F %%I IN ("!value!") DO SET MYPATHFILE=%%~nxI
)
```

Comment: How can i delete the last character from the MYPATHFILE ?

Comment: `set "MYPATHFILE=%MYPATHFILE:~0,-1%` , but you need to do this outside of the for loop.

Comment: is there any possibility to do it in the second loop?

Comment: @HamstersBlue - then yu'll need to use delyaed expansion: `set "MYPATHFILE=!MYPATHFILE:~0,-1!"`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you will need Delayed Expansion.

The current problem is, that you want to use a variable in the same set of brackets where you changed the value in (the surrounding For-Loop).

Add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your code at the top and change the `%value%` to `!value!`

You can test the problem yourself with this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set foo=bar
For /L %%a (1,2,1) do (
set foo=foobar
echo.old value %foo%
echo.new value !foo!
)
```

I hope it helped :)

Greetings

geisterfurz007